# LocalNotification based on user location

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, notifications

Someone know how we can Trigger Localnotification based on user lastknowlocation and some statics locations (LAng,LAnt) (like geofoncing)?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Xamarin.Forms, i would recommend you take a look at the Xamarin.Essentials: Geolocation nuget package. For more information click here [Xamarin Essentials Geo Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=android)

Comment: I have used this my question now is how we can manage Notification "App stoped or not" by using location changes from device " I heared about Service/ JobSchudled" but im not sure about that.

Comment: Are you relating to Device Notification?

Comment: Yeah  à local notification but just for a users that they are closed to some areas.

Comment: You can try this plugin [link](https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin) with the geo location plugin to create the implementation you are talking about.

Comment: thank you, i tried this plugin but my issues is how can i combine Datetime to execute a notification and user location.